# wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 (with patched qt) generates blank page

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

Using the above version of wkhtmltopdf, I have a php file that generates a pdf from a url. If I include the tag --lowquality, I get a blank page at the beginning of the pdf.

I need to include the --lowquality tag as the content of the url I send is to great to generate w/o --lowquality.

adds blank page...

```
<?php
require_once('wkhtmltopdf.php');

$pdf_file_name = "report.pdf";
$URL = $_GET['URL'];

if(isset($URL)){ 
    try {
        $pdf=new WKPDF();   
        $pdf->set_url($URL);
        $pdf->args_add("--javascript-delay", "3000");
        $pdf->args_add("--zoom", ".7");
        $pdf->args_add("--margin-top", "5");
        $pdf->args_add("--margin-bottom", "5");

        $pdf->args_add("--lowquality");

        $pdf->args_add("--load-error-handling", "ignore");
        $pdf->render();
        $pdf->output(WKPDF::$PDF_DOWNLOAD,$pdf_file_name);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        die('Exception (line '.$e->getLine().'): '.$e->getMessage());
    }
}
?>
```

doesn't...

```
<?php
require_once('wkhtmltopdf.php');

$pdf_file_name = "report.pdf";
$URL = $_GET['URL'];

if(isset($URL)){ 
    try {
        $pdf=new WKPDF();   
        $pdf->set_url($URL);
        $pdf->args_add("--javascript-delay", "3000");
        $pdf->args_add("--zoom", ".7");
        $pdf->args_add("--margin-top", "5");
        $pdf->args_add("--margin-bottom", "5");

        //$pdf->args_add("--lowquality");

        $pdf->args_add("--load-error-handling", "ignore");
        $pdf->render();
        $pdf->output(WKPDF::$PDF_DOWNLOAD,$pdf_file_name);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        die('Exception (line '.$e->getLine().'): '.$e->getMessage());
    }
}
?>
```

Is there a way to use --lowquality and not get the blank page included?

Comment: If I remove ("--load-error-handling", "ignore") - I get the following error...  content-type missing in HTTP POST, defaulting to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Use QNetworkRequest::setHeader() to fix this problem.

Comment: Looks like you're passing the URL via `$_GET`. First thing I would do in your place is check that the URL isn't being urlencoded into something that's not a URL